# Inject ui-router resolve result on controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to inject this fieldsList variable resolved by a service in a controller but I've got an error:

```
projectApp = angular.module('projectApp', ['ui.router']);

projectApp.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider.state('initial', {
        url: '/',
        template: 'Hi !'
    })

    .state('fields', {
        url: '/customers/fields',
        resolve: {
            fieldsList: function (fieldService) {
                return fieldService.getFields();
            }
        },
        views: {
            '': {
                controller: 'fieldController',
                templateUrl: '/static/app/customers/pages/fields.html'
            },
            'list@fields': {
                controller: 'fieldListController',
                templateUrl: '/static/app/customers/pages/fields.list.html'
            }
        }
    })

    //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);    
});
```

// The controller

```
projectApp.controller('fieldListController', ['$scope, $http', 'fieldsList', function($scope, $http, fieldsList) {

    this.fieldsList = fieldsList;

    console.log(this.fieldsList);
}]);
```

// The error:

```
angular.min.js:124 Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.6.6/$injector/unpr?p0=%24scope%2C%20%24httpProvider%20%3C-%20%24scope%2C%20%24http%20%3C-%20fieldListController
    at angular.min.js:7
    at angular.min.js:46
    at Object.d [as get] (angular.min.js:43)
    at angular.min.js:46
    at d (angular.min.js:43)
    at e (angular.min.js:44)
    at Object.instantiate (angular.min.js:44)
    at angular.min.js:95
    at Object.<anonymous> (angular-ui-router.min.js:11)
    at angular.min.js:17 "<div class="row mt-4 ml-1 mr-1 ng-scope" ui-view="list">"
```

Can anyone take a look at this and please say what I'm doing wrong ?
PS: I can log the webservice the data. So It seems at least the service works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening simply because your controller's injection array has `'$scope, $http'` as one string.
Split the two dependencies like this:

```
['$scope', '$http', 'fieldsList', function($scope, $http, fieldsList) {
```

This should solve the error.